# Control the "this" context on callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, listener, this

I have a listener like this one :

```
this.frame.on('touchend', self.findClosestSlide);
```

I need to have it like this, instead of inside an anonymous function in order to be able to unbind it later, using the function name.

My problem is that, once I am in the `findClosestSlide` function, my `this` object logically becomes `this.frame`.

How can I access the original `this`, or how can I have control on the context I'm sending to my callback function? (without using an anonymous function)

Comment: `this.frame.on('touchend', self.findClosestSlide.bind(this));`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Function.bind() or $.proxy() to pass a custom context to a callback like

Cross Browser, use [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy)

```
this.frame.on('touchend', $.proxy(self.findClosestSlide, self));
```

or [IE9+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Browser_compatibility), use [function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
this.frame.on('touchend', self.findClosestSlide.bind(self));
```

Why? because by default `this` inside the event handler will refer to the element that was targeted by the event

Answer (score 2):

You can store `this` inside another variable such as `that` or `$this` than using it inside your `findClosestSlide` function.

Comment: I used Arun's answer instead but +1, since it would work. Thanks :)